# Getting a stack trace of your executed code with Jasmine BDD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I've been using Jasmine to test my Rails application's javascript code. However, when i run rake jasmine and view the webpage. The stack traces for failed expectations just show the jasmine.js file, not my code. Is there a way to get it to show where my code is failing like in Rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else runs into this issue, i found using the jasmine-headless-webkit gem helps a lot.